# Basic inserting of image? Python

Tags: python, image

I use python on Ubuntu, and I am (as my name suggests) a complete noob at it all. I want to insert a very basic image, I have looked around, copied coding etc, but mothing seems to work. I want to insert an image, nothing else, so it just appears on the screen when I run it in shell. Please help? and please explain in simple terms, i'd like to know what I'm actually doing! Thank-you in advance.

Comment: This is not really a basic task, since you have to create a window and everything. However try looking at pygame, it has this capability.

Comment: Generally, I just don't know the answers to SO questions. Now, I don't even know what the question is. :|

Comment: I am just asking how to insert an image, using python coding, so that when i hit f5 and run the code in shell, an image will appear. I don't get how you don't know what i'm talking about?!?!?

Answer (score 3):

you can install PIL imagemagick

then:

```
import Image

im = Image.open("your_image")
im.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('file:///path/to/my/file.jpg')
```

Comment: why -1 after all it open the image in a new window?